# Error on ordering of methods in controller Nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have this basic CRUD methods in Nestjs.
The issue I am facing is that when I am applying the `getCurrentUserId()` method on top on all methods it works fine but when I am applying in bottom it doesnt work and gives error.
Is there anything wrong with middleware ?

`user.controller.ts`

```
@Controller('users')
@Serialize(UserDto)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post('/signup')
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
  }

  @Get('/@:userName')
  async getUserByUsername(@Param('userName') userName: string) {
    const user = await this.usersService.findByName(userName);
    console.log(userName);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User Not Found');
    }

    return user;
  }

  //! Testing for current user
  @Get('/current')
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  async getCurrentUserId(@CurrentUser() id: string) {
    console.log('running endpoint');
    return id;
  }
}
```

`current-user.decorator.ts`

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data : unknown , context : ExecutionContext) => {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    console.log("I am running")
    return req.id;
  }
)
```

`current-user.middleware.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class CurrentUserMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  async use(req: RequestId, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const token = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Unauthorized');
    }
    try {
      const { userId } =
        await this.usersService.getUserByToken(token);
      req.id = userId;
      console.log(req.id)
      next();
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  }
}
```

And I have added the middleware to `user.module.ts` like this

```
export class UsersModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(CurrentUserMiddleware).forRoutes(
      'users/current'
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ```[Nest] 7533  - 10/08/2021, 11:04:41 am   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] invalid input syntax for type uuid: "current"
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "current"```

this error when I am applying `getCurrentUserId()` at bottom

Comment: Which nestjs version?

Comment: nestjs version : 8.1.1

Comment: I think there something with middleware path issue.. And I am not able to resolve that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The route is matching on `@Get('/@:userName')` before it makes it to `@Get('/current')` so its executing the code inside of your `getUserByUsername` method instead.

Just move `getCurrentUserId` to the top and you should be fine.

Routes are evaluated in the order they are defined and the first matching one is used to handle the request. In general you should always put the most specific routes (the ones without route params) at the top of your controller to avoid this problem.

Comment: Aah I see. I thought there is some issue with my middleware. And yeah if the `getCurrentUserId` is at top it works fine. I thought all the routes are independent of each other (like order doesn't matter).

Comment: It's not practical for routes to be entirely independent since it's totally possible for multiple paths to match any given request. 

This isn't specific to NestJS but applies to basically any HTTP framework that does route mapping with parameterized URLs. You would have the same issue working directly with Express.js.

If this solved your issue please consider marking this answer as accepted