# How to deal with NestJS @Get() decorator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

This block of code works properly. I'm able to access both functions with the URL
http://localhost:3000/vehicle/availableVehicles
& http://localhost:3000/vehicle/1 accordingly

```
    @Controller('vehicle')
    export class VehicleController {
        constructor(
            private readonly vehicleService: VehicleService,
            private readonly crudService: CurdService
        ) { }
        tableName: string = 'vehicle';
    
        @Get('availableVehicles')
        async availableVehicles() {
            return await this.vehicleService.availableVehicles();
        }
        
        @Get(':id')
        async getbyId(@Req() request: Request) {
            return await this.crudService.getById(this.tableName, request.params.id);
        }
  }
```

**But when I just swap between the 2 functions like code block below then the function `availableVehicles()` doesn't work & the URL** http://localhost:3000/vehicle/availableVehicles **hits the `getbyId()` function. What to do? Or what I'm doing wrong?** Thanks in advance.

```
    @Controller('vehicle')
    export class VehicleController {
        constructor(
            private readonly vehicleService: VehicleService,
            private readonly crudService: CurdService
        ) { }
        tableName: string = 'vehicle';

        @Get(':id')
        async getbyId(@Req() request: Request) {
            return await this.crudService.getById(this.tableName, request.params.id);
        }
    
        @Get('availableVehicles')
        async availableVehicles() {
            return await this.vehicleService.availableVehicles();
        }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on ordering of methods in controller Nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721406/error-on-ordering-of-methods-in-controller-nestjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do exactly what you did in the first example, put the more specific routes above the ones that take route parameters.

When the server's routing table is being built on application startup they will be discovered and registered in this order.

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68727403/1364771

Comment: Thanks & accepted your answer but is there any other way so that I don't have to think about the ordering?

Comment: No its not possible. Both routes match so, how should it determine which one to use? It can't use both, so you as the developer need to provide a "tie breaker". Currently that is only done through the ordering of the route definitions.