# Why does supertest/jest always call the same endpoint when I clearly insert a different path in my test? Is there some config I need to set?

Tags: api, jestjs, nestjs, supertest, e2e

this is my controller class:

```js
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: InferenceFile,
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      model: {
        eager: true,
      },
      file: {
        eager: true,
      },
    },
  },
  params: {
    id: {
      type: 'uuid',
      primary: true,
      field: 'id',
    },
  },
})
@Controller('inference-files')
export class InferenceFilesController {
  constructor(private service: InferenceFilesService) {
  }

  @Get('list/:algorithmId')
  async getAllInferenceFiles(
    @Param('algorithmId') algorithmId: number,
    @Query('name') name: string,
    @Query('page') page: number = 0,
    @Query('size') limit: number = 1000,
  ) {
    return await this.service.findAllByAlgorithmId(algorithmId, name, {
      page,
      limit,
    });
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async get(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const result = await this.service.getFile(id);

    result.presignedUrl = await this.service.getPresignedDownloadUrl(result);
    result.presignedWordsUrl = await this.service.getPresignedWordsUrl(result);
    return result;
  }

  @Get('status')
  async getStatus(@Query('modelId') modelId: number) {
    return await this.service.getStatus(modelId);
  }
}
```

This is part of my test class where it goes wrong:

```js
it('should return an array of inference file statuses', async () => {
    // Act
    let modelIdToPass = setUp.model1.id;
    const { body } = await supertest
      .agent(setUp.app.getHttpServer())
      .get(`/inference-files/status?${modelIdToPass}`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200);

    // Assert
    expect(body).toEqual({
      'test-id-2': 'FINISHED',
    });
  });

  it('should return the inference file for the given id', async () => {
    // Act
    const { body } = await supertest
      .agent(setUp.app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/inference-files/' + TestConstants.INFERENCEFILE_ID_1)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200);

    // Assert
    expect(body).toEqual({
      'test-id-1': 'FINISHED',
    });
  });

  it('should return the inference file for the given algorithm id', async () => {
    // Act
    const { body } = await supertest
      .agent(setUp.app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/inference-files/list/' + 9)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200);

    // Assert
    expect(body).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Al of these tests call the same endpoint:  @Get(':id')
But when I comment two out of the three of them out, it succeeds.. Or better yet, it calls the remaining "Get" method. I have been looking for an answer for a whole day, but no one seems to have experienced the same problem..

When I look at the documentation online, it doesn't mention anything about routing for this. I also do not wish to mock the implementation (I've seen examples of the routing with express). But that is not what I'm looking for. I wish to test the whole flow, so it needs to call (all or most of) my methods. I use a separate database for testing, so no mocking needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on ordering of methods in controller Nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721406/error-on-ordering-of-methods-in-controller-nestjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the endpoint for `@Get('status')` above the one for `@Get(':id')` in your controller.

Because `:id` comes first, it is assuming that `status` is actually an id value and is therefore invoking the wrong handler.

When a request comes to your server all the routes are evaluated one at a time and the first matching route is selected to handle the request.

This is a duplicate of [Error on ordering of methods in controller Nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721406/error-on-ordering-of-methods-in-controller-nestjs/68727403#68727403) and [How to deal with NestJS @Get() decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258837/how-to-deal-with-nestjs-get-decorator/69258909#69258909) which were both asked recently

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I had absolutely no idea the order mattered. Which is also why I didn't land on the other stackoverflow pages

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out